# Subtract group aggregate values in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that stores a users voting value `voteTypeID = 1` for up vote and `voteTypeID = 2` for a down vote and a `loadoutID` that ties back to another collection.

I want to group by `loadoutID` and take all up-votes and subtract all down-votes, to get the difference.  So if a loadout has *20* up-votes and *2* down-votes, I would like to get back **18** as well as the `loadoutID`.

I admit I am fairly new to the aggregate function and have only used it for basic counts before and it just hasnt clicked yet for me, any help greatly appreciated.  The more you could explain the aggregate the better =)

**Here is my most recent failed attempt**

```
LoadoutVotes.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$loadoutID',
            up: { $sum: { voteTypeID: 1}},
            down: { $sum: { voteTypeID: 2 }}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$loadoutID',
            count: {$subtract: ['$up', '$down']}
        }
    }
])
```

**JSON data**

```
{
  loadoutID: 'ObjectID-String',
  voteTypeID: 1
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator in the aggregation framework takes an argument that is a numeric value which is applied to the grouping. Typically you want this to be either the value of a field in the document or a value like `1` when you want to count the occurrences.

What you are trying to do is "conditionally" evaluate a field value, and for this there is the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator. This would determine which value to apply depending on your `voteTypeID` field. So you could write like this:

```js
LoaodoutVotes.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$loadoutID",
       "up": { 
           "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$voteTypeID", 1 ] },
                   1,
                   0
               ]
           }
       },
       "down": { 
           "$sum": { 
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$voteTypeID", 2 ] },
                   1,
                   0
               ]
           }
       },
    }},
    { "$project": {
       "loadoutID": "$_id",
       "count": { "$subtract": [ "$up", "$down" ] }
    }}
])
```

Or even more efficiently like this as you can "sign" the values in-line:

```js
LoaodoutVotes.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$loadoutID",
       "count": {
           "$sum": {
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$voteTypeID", 1 ] },
                   1,
                   { "$cond": [
                      { "$eq": [ "$voteTypeID", 2 ] },
                      -1,
                       0
                   ]}
               ]
           }
       }
    }}
])
```

So it is much more efficient as **`$group`** is now just a single pass in the pipeline. Since **`$cond`** is a ternary operator ( if-then-else ) then the conditions can be stacked in-line as well. So either positive or negative or nothing.

Comment: First time ever seeing the $cond operator.  SO $eq: [voteTypeID, 1] is the 'if' statement, which returns a 1 and the else links to another $cond that will return back a -1 if the votetypeID is 2 or default to zero to not affect sum.  Appreciate that, I dont think I would of figured this one out so quickly =)